# remove string from url (.htaccess)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My URL looks something like this:

```
example.com/index.php?redirected=1
```

in my `.htaccess`-file, I want to remove the last part of my url.

I wrote that:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com\/index.php\?redirected=1$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But for some reason, it isn't working. It is right after the line:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
```

I found similar questions, but that didn't do the trick.
Thanks

With this code in the .htaccess-file, it redirects me to: www.example.com/index.php

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+(.*)\?redirected=1&?([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1?%2 [L,R]
```

When i remove the %2 (which i thought was the `index.php`-part, it'll result in infinte redirects.

Update:
I updated the regexp like this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+(.*)\?redirected=1&?([^\ ]*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

still the "index.php" in the end

Comment: What URL do you want your rule to be redirected to?

Comment: perfect would be: example.com (so without index.php at the end)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule for stripping query string and as well as removing `index.php`:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?redirected=1[&\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1? [L,R=302,NC,NE]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+(.*)\?redirect=1&?([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1?%2 [L,R]
```

The `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable is **only the hostname**, it contains no path or query string in it.

Comment: That almost works for me, thanks so far already! Is there a way to remove the `index.php` as well? - I'll update the question